# How can I display the full suit value like Hearts or Clubs?

Tags: c++11

I have a class for storing the details of a single card. Although I have a function to give me the character representing the suit, what I'd really like is the full word representing that suit (like "Hearts").

How can I do this? The code is below:

```
class Card
{
    private:
        int value;  // stores value of card(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
        char suit;  // stores suit of card('h','d','s','c'
        char card;  // stores card symbol(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,k,q,j,a)

    public:
        void setValue(int v)         {value = v;}  
        void setCard(char c)         {card = c;} 
        void setSuit(char s)         {suit = s;} 


        int getValue()        {return value;} 
        char getSuit()        {return suit;} 
        char getCard()        {return card;} 

        void display();
};


void Card :: display()   // display member function
{
    cout << "Value is: " << getValue() << endl; 
    cout << "Suit is : " << getSuit() << endl; 

    cout << "Card is: " << getCard() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with something like:

```
std::string getFullSuit() {
    if (suit == 's') return "Spades";
    if (suit == 'c') return "Clubs";
    if (suit == 'd') return "Diamonds";
    if (suit == 'h') return "Hearts";
    return "No idea!";
}
```

But, just as an aside, it's probably better to use an `enum` (rather than a `char`) for this sort of thing, since that more naturally lends itself to type checking (almost certainly removing the need for the `"No idea!"` code above).